# Issue in cache replication Ignite

Tags: rest, ignite

I have created an ignite cache in the following java code.

```
    CacheConfiguration cfg3 = new CacheConfiguration();
    cfg3.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
    cfg3.setName("all_log");
    IgniteCache<String, String> cache3 = ig.getOrCreateCache(cfg3);
```

I have an ignite cluster and i am trying to modify the ignite cache using REST APIs gven here. https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api

I removed a particular key from the cache using the following request.
    http://10.145.59.25:8080/ignite?cmd=rmv&key=updown&cacheName=all_log

However, when i try to fetch the key from another server which is part of the ignite cluster using the following command: 
http://10.145.59.85:8080/ignite?cmd=get&key=updown&cacheName=all_log

i get the following response:

```
response    "| Log which shows the timestamps for change in up-down status of     shards\nDatabase initialised at Thu Jul 19 16:18:31 2018\n"
```

indicating that the key is present. The same issue is there for get and put commands as well. When i put a value into a key of a given cache, its values are changed only in the server whose IP i mention in the http request.

However, replication is successful when i put a key into a cache for the first time.

EDIT::: I checked the ignite topology using http://10.145.59.85:8080/ignite?cmd=top&attr=true&mtr=true

I observed that the cluster is getting partitioned as soon as a put request is done.

Comment: Sounds like a segmentation issue - your nodes could've lost each other (e.g. due to network error) and form two separate clusters. Please share the logs - they should contain messages about this.

Comment: Do you see, that response is successful? Did you check, if the value is present on a node, that you removed the value from?